# Poor font choices in plots after compiling R from source

Tags: r, plot

I recently compiled R from source on Linux Mint 17 and everything is working correctly except my plots take a long time to load and the default font is quite bland [(see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYa1Y.jpg).

My sessionInfo is below:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.1.1 tools_3.1.1
```

I checked the  [R installation and administration manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html), but I'm not sure which (if any) ./configure options I missed.

Is there any way to fix this issue, or will I have to recompile R?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: More information:

```
    > X11.options()
$display
[1] ""

$width
[1] NA

$height
[1] NA

$pointsize
[1] 12

$bg
[1] "transparent"

$canvas
[1] "white"

$gamma
[1] 1

$colortype
[1] "true"

$maxcubesize
[1] 256

$fonts
[1] "-adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"
[2] "-adobe-symbol-medium-r-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

$family
[1] "sans"

$xpos
[1] NA

$ypos
[1] NA

$title
[1] ""

$type
[1] "Xlib"

$antialias
[1] "default"
```

It clearly looks like other fonts are available, but specifying `par(family="")` still gives me the previously pictured plot style.

Comment: `?par`; `par(family = 'sans')`. it is not comic sans unfortunately

Comment: My understanding is that (default) fonts are based upon what's available to the graphics device, which will depend on your OS not your R installation, I believe.

Comment: And... where is the code? `sessionInfo()` does not tell us what graphic device you are using.

Comment: @DavidArenburg whenever I have installed R from the package manager, the plots look more like [this](http://orgmode.org/worg/images/org-R/org-plot-example-1.png).

Comment: @rawr That option results in the same plot as I produced before.

Comment: @BondedDust dev.cur() returns NULL, but when I adjust it to X11, I end up with the same plot.  I'm not sure what other code to provide.

Comment: You are seeing the default settings for `X11Fonts()`. Read the Index for the pkg:grDevices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked around a bit more, and it appears that I did not allow for cairo support when I compiled R.  Following [these instructions](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-fedora/2013-January/000290.html), I recompiled R with the option `--with-cairo` and now I am able to adjust the font size and family when plotting.